# How To Filter 15k Products In Shopify Store?

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

So, my client using Dawn theme with 15000 products in the store. He asked me how to filter all of these products. I used metafields to filter 100 products and barely died, but 15k it's too much to add filters manually, I mean it will take the whole life to filter them properly. Any ideas how we can add filters to the products faster?

I read [Shopify Admin API](https://shopify.dev/api/admin) documentation and it seems that for client it will be complex to add some code for products filtering (I didn't understand either). It'll be okay if it possible.

Also I tried to export CSV file of the products, but it doesn't export the metafields of the products.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Michael, I'm sorry but I don't get exactly what the problem is. Do you need to add metafields to specify an attribute that is not already in the product? You can add metafields using the API but for filtering is better to use an app or create your own endpoint.

Comment: Hi Fabio. Thank you for your comment. The problem is in filtering the products that now in the store and those that will be in the store in the future. Thanks for an advice, I will research about it.

Comment: If I will use an app, I'll need to add a key of the metafield to each product, isn't it?

Comment: If you want to filter on things that are not already in the product details. Typically you already have colour/size/type of product in the product details. If you need more you will need metafields.